# Gridview itemclick in pivot

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I have a gridview in an pivot control and I want to call a method on the viewmodel when a griditem is clicked (with an item id).  I'm on a UWP project with Template10

My xaml looks like:

```
<Pivot Name="FeedsPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding Feeds, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Feed">
            <GridView Name="ArticlesGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles, Mode=OneWay}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <userControls:FeedControl />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

I thought I could use something like this on the gridview:

```
ItemClick="{Binding ClickCommand, ElementName=ViewModel}"
```

But I always get *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* on the viewmodel context.
The viewmodel is referenced in the page like :

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

I also tried to give the page a name and use that in the *ElementName*

Any help about best practices here?  Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I could use something like this on the gridview:ItemClick="{Binding ClickCommand, ElementName=ViewModel}"

We cannot directly set the `Binding` object to [ItemClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) event. In your senario the [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) SDK is recommended to use. We can use a [CallMethodAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/CallMethodAction) for the `Itemclick` EventTriggerBehavior like follows, pay attention to enable the `IsItemClickEnable` for the `GridView`.

XAML code as follows:

```
 <GridView Name="ArticlesGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding feeds, Mode=OneWay}"  IsItemClickEnabled="True"   >
     <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">             
             <Core:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="ArticlesGridView_ItemClick" />
           </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
       </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Vipclass">
            ...
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemTemplate>
 </GridView>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind in `MainPageViewModel.cs` like follows:

```
 public void ArticlesGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
    ...
 }
```

The `ElementName` bind in above code snippet is the page object. For more details about how to use and install `XamlBehaviors` please reference the [wiki of XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki). You can also install the SDK by [Xaml.Behaviors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) Nuget package.